# Are there any advantages of static NodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

My quesion is emerged from Todd Motto's [A comprehensive dive into NodeLists, Arrays, converting NodeLists and understanding the DOM](http://toddmotto.com/a-comprehensive-dive-into-nodelists-arrays-converting-nodelists-and-understanding-the-dom/) article.

As for methods such as `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, which do not have both advantages of live collections and useful Array-like methods (e.g. `forEach`), why they are implemented as static collections and not Arrays (or at least don't use Array prototype)? Are there any advantages of using *static* NodeList over Array?

Comment: As a I guess, I would say 1. to preserve consistency (it would seem odd to return Array instead of NodeList), and 2. static to prevent live requerying (which could be expensive).

Comment: I'd use [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js) and you can see Todd Motto's and I twitter conversation [here](https://twitter.com/16JSDev/status/625363187353952257) you'll have to keep scrolling to see his replies